# When is it right to use native menus for desktop apps?

Tags: desktop-application

I am building a video chat desktop app, and it has a window to emulate a custom menu. I have seen many desktop apps that use native menus, and it is pretty common. Other desktop apps use custom menus, for some things, for instance, Slack uses a custom one for its main menu. So, is there anything bad about custom menus or native ones? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "native menu" in this context? Can you provide an example of both a native and custom menu? That way we can better understand your question.

Comment: By native menu, I mean the native menu widget the OS provides. For instance this is a Skype one: https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1kXQoLLp9o5bVfomNiGqxA_YkJnGiXA5C=w3072-h1762-iv1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question for which I have spent a lot of time researching. From my experience, it all comes down to **immersiveness** .

I usually recommend and even insist on using the guidelines of the platforms we are designing for (e.g. Material for Android apps). I do this because the app will fit better with the rest of the system.

Of course, you don't have to follow the guidelines to a tee, otherwise you risk making your product look like a stock app that comes pre-installed with the system. Here, you have to bring in brand elements and find a balance between them and the system you are designing for.